# How can I make responsive design in IFrame for mobile, tablets?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, responsive-design

How can I make Iframe responsive and save this proportions for Desktop view:
height: 1100px;
width: 1600px;

I have a specified code to embed IFrame:

HTML:

```
<html> 
  <body> 
    <div class="parent">
      <iframe id="iframe" src=""></iframe>
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
      <script src="main.js"></script> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 1100px; 
  width: 1600px; 
    right: 50%;

}

.overlay {
  background-color: #201E34;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 28px;
  width: 100%
}


iframe { 
  height: 100%;
  resize: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('#iframe'); 
iframe.loading = 'lazy';
iframe.setAttribute('src', 'https://datastudio.google.com/embed/reporting/23309a0f-9bdc-4c62-9f4c-5d58591e1017/page/VgD');
```

Do you have any suggestions to edit css or add additions JS function

Answer (score -1):

Iframe in html it´s deprecated. Maybe yo can use modal window or other page. Iframe always have a fixed size.

Comment: iframes are very much not deprecated

Comment: @dantheman it´s better to use other system to create app web or websites more modern

Comment: iframes are incredibly useful for the scenarios that call for it. To say it is deprecated is false. Stackoverflow itself uses iframes for code previews.

Comment: Please check https://www.elliottmellichamp.com/responsive-google-data-studio-embed if it's usefull, the issue is that the iframe src has not `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` head tag, that make it responsive.